# Old Movie, College rejects get brainwashed into being model citizens

Tags: story-identification

The hero moves to a new city and makes friends with a bunch of normal college students.

- As soon as they go to the local college, they seem to get brainwashed into being nerds who all wear same kind of uniform.
- He will be going to that college too. One day one of his friends gets converted.
- I remember there were also mind experiments going on.
- The movie name starts with D.

Answer (score 8):

This is "[Disturbing Behaviour](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0134619/)"

> *The new kid in town stumbles across something sinister about the town's method of transforming its unruly teens into upstanding
>   citizens.*

Comment: The only caveat there might be the "nerd" aspect of it. As I recall it, they generally dressed more like jocks and preppies, letterman jackets and all that. Also, I think Disturbing Behavior was entirely set around a high school, not a college.

Comment: @SeanDuggan - It's close though. I shall be most surprised if this isn't it.